# Default with Date not working with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following data model:

```
overall_stats: {
        elo: {
            type: Array,
            default: {
                date: Date.now,
                ranking: 1000,
            }
        },
 ....
```

If I put a number instead of Date.now it works but like that it doesn't. I assume its because the field is not declared as a date. However I tried a lot of different options to declare it but never got the syntax right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date.now` is a function so to make it work, you need to put `Date.now()` or if you want a date instead of a number then `new Date()` will help:

```
overall_stats: {
    elo: {
        type: Array,
        default: {
            date: new Date(),
            ranking: 1000,
        }
    },
....
```

Comment: but that gives me the unix time as a number instead of the MongoDB date like 2020-02-25T22:29:59.029Z. 
date: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now
 },
works for example

Comment: In this case, `new Date()` will help.

Comment: I get the same result (unix time string) with new Date()

Comment: @solaire From what I gather what u are looking for is indeed `new Date()` which would be native javascript date object. Which at the time of insertion into mongodb will be wrapped with `ISODate()` `eg: 2020-02-25T22:29:59.029Z` (mongodb does that for u).

Comment: Was an error on my side, new Date() does work :) Feel free to adapt your answer then i accept it

Comment: @solaire The op of answer has changed it to `new Date()` correctly. You can accept and upvote this itself.